# Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string'

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to iterate a set of array values returned from my laravel view in a multi-select dropdown field. When I submit my form, below is the data sent to my livewire component.

```
 ^ array:4 [▼
      "scheduled_date" => "2022-09-30 12:00"
      "recipient" => "2"
      "classrooms" => array:4 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "3"
        2 => "4"
        3 => "5"
      ]
      "smsdetail" => "Testing for a particular Class"
    ]
```

I need to iterate data in classrooms array and save them as different records with the rest of the top-level data to db which is not the problem. My struggle is to iterate and pick values for classrooms.

The below set of codes gives me the error Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string'. I need help.

```
case ('2'):
     $recipients = $this->state['classrooms'];
     foreach ($recipients as $key => $recipient) 
    {
      dd($recipient);
                   
     }


  case ('2'):
     $recipients = $this->state['classrooms'];
     foreach ($recipients as $recipient) 
     {
        dd($recipient);
     }
```

Comment: foreach expects 'iterable|object'. Are you sure the error is thrown at this line?
you should ```dd($this->state['classrooms'])```

Comment: $recipients = $this->state['classrooms'];
                //  dd($recipients);
                foreach($recipients as $recipient) // There error is thrown on the foreach

Comment: could you please share the output of iteration?

Comment: if you dd() it should not even continue to foreach

Comment: It works with a foreach even though IDE still shows error...... foreach ($recipients as $i => $value) {
                    dump($recipients[$i]);
                }

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will figure out now why IDE Showing erro and fix that.